# Using Hyperloop to incorporate appanalytics.io - iOS

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop

I'm trying to integrate the iOS SDK for AppAnalytics.io into my titanium app using HyperLoop. I am using the 'AppAnalytics' cocoapod.

I would like to: a) double check that I am doing it correctly as this is my first Hyperloop implementation

b) try and find the fix to the issue i am having.

My code:

```
var AAppAnalytics = require('AppAnalytics/AppAnalytics');
var appAnalytics = new AAppAnalytics();

appAnalytics.initWithAppKey('my apikey');
```

When I run the app, the cocoapod seems to install correctly but the app crashes with the following error:

```
The application has crashed with an uncaught exception 'App Analytics Exception'.
Reason:
SDK is used without being initialized
```

The only thing I can think is because the init code is not being run in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as is requested on their website http://appanalytics.io/Support.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?  I'm trying to implement some code that requires didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as well.  I know that you can access it with native iOS module, but haven't found the solution yet.

Comment: no sorry i never did :-(

Comment: new HL 3.0.1 have some solutions.  also I've compiled a github repo with relevant Hyperloop info that might help: https://github.com/shouse/awesome-hyperloop-titanium/